# Aplicação fechando sozinha após holder.textViewVar.setVisibility

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Tenho um `RecyclerView` e em cada item gostaria de verificar se um fato ocorresse para mostrar ou não um botão:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Posts post = Posts.get(position);
    holder.post = post;

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    //parte nova que trava (essas 7 linhas):
    String lk = post.getLk();
    if (lk.equals("1")) { //show button
        holder.textViewUnlk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else { //hide
        holder.textViewLk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }



    holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());

    holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

O `textViewLk` e o `textViewUnlk` estão no XML como `GONE`. O que pode ser?

Comment: Bem vindo! Por favor, pedimos que realize um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site e veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Se possível adicione os erros mostrados no Log da Aplicação! Isto ajuda as pessoas a te ajudar!

Comment: O **post.getLk()** pode estar nulo! Mas se o log de erro fica bem difícil!

Comment: Você provavelmente não está inflando as views corretamente na classe viewholder. Seria melhor se postasse o adapter do recycler view por compelto.